# R: results differ when calculating Euclidean distance between two vectors with different methods

Tags: r, euclidean-distance

Suppose that I have two vectors.

```
x1 = c(-1, 2, 3)
x2 = c(4, 0, -3)
```

To calculate the Euclidean distance, I used three different ways

1- The built function `norm`

```
s = cbind(x1, x2)
norm(s, "2")
#[1] 5.797896
```

2- Hand calculation

```
sqrt(sum(x2 - x1) ^ 2)
#[1] 8.062258
```

3- custom function

```
lpnorm <- function(x, p){  
  n <- sum(abs(x) ^ p) ^ (1 / p)
  return(n)
  }

lpnorm(s, 2)
#[1] 6.244998
```

Why I got different results?

If I am wrong, how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `s = x2 - x1`.

```
norm(s, "2")
#[1] 8.062258

sqrt(sum(s ^ 2))  ## or: sqrt(c(crossprod(s)))
#[1] 8.062258

lpnorm(s, 2)
#[1] 8.062258
```

If you define `s = cbind(x1, x2)`, none of the options you listed is going to compute the Euclidean distance between `x1` and `x2`, but we can still get them output the same value. In this case they the L2 norm of the vector `c(x1, x2)`.

```
norm(s, "F")
#[1] 6.244998

sqrt(sum(s ^ 2))
#[1] 6.244998

lpnorm(s, 2)
#[1] 6.244998
```

Finally, `norm` is not a common way for computing distance. It is really for matrix norm. When you do `norm(cbind(x1, x2), "2")`, it computes the L2 matrix norm which is the largest singular value of matrix `cbind(x1, x2)`.

---

> So my problem is with defining `s`. Ok, what if I have more than three vectors?

In that case you want pairwise Euclidean matrix. See function `?dist`.

> I have the train sets (containing three or more rows) and one test set (one row). So, I would like to calculate the Euclidean distance or may be other distances. This is the reason why I want to make sure about the distance calculation.

You want the distance between one vector and each of many others, and the result is a vector?

```
set.seed(0)
X_train <- matrix(runif(10), 5, 2)
x_test <- runif(2)
S <- t(X_train) - x_test

apply(S, 2, norm, "2")  ## don't try other types than "2"
#[1] 0.8349220 0.7217628 0.8012416 0.6841445 0.9462961

apply(S, 2, lpnorm, 2)
#[1] 0.8349220 0.7217628 0.8012416 0.6841445 0.9462961

sqrt(colSums(S ^ 2))  ## only for L2-norm
#[1] 0.8349220 0.7217628 0.8012416 0.6841445 0.9462961
```

---

I would stress again that `norm` would fail on a vector, unless `type = "2"`. `?norm` clearly says that this function is intended for **matrix**. What `norm` does is very different from your self-defined `lpnorm` function. `lpnorm` is for a **vector norm**, `norm` is for a **matrix norm**. Even "L2" means differently for a matrix and a vector.